# str_replace() is not working in aws server returning empty string but working on cpanel and locally

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, amazon-ec2, str-replace

I am developing a laravel ride sharing applicaiton and for the settings data I used a config files. To change any value usign file file_get_contents after that with str_replace and file_put_contents for updating the value.
here is some code example:

```
$config = base_path() . '/config/constants.php';
$file = file_get_contents($config);
$change_content = $file;
foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {

        $value = (trim($value) == 'on') ? '1' : trim($value);
        $searchfor = config('constants.' . $key);
        if ($value != $searchfor) {
            $search_text = "'" . $key . "' => '" . $searchfor . "'";
            $value_text = "'" . $key . "' => '" . $value . "'";
            $change_content = str_replace($search_text, $value_text, $change_content);
        }

        file_put_contents($config, $change_content);
    }
```

But the $change_content doesn't return any value in the AWS server

NOTE: This is working in my local machine also in Cpanel but in AWS ec2 not working. I am using php7.4, Nginx in Ubuntu 20.04. Same configuration for Cpanel, local, and AWS ec2.

Can anyone tell me that is there any extra configuration for str_replcae??

Comment: are you sure that the path is correct and your have read (and write) permission on the file ?

Comment: remove $change_c...= $file then, within the str_replace($search_t......) replace $change_content with $file

Comment: @KenLee Yes the file has correct permission and by default, I am getting the file content without str_replcae

Comment: @KevinGales But this is working fine in my local machine also in cpanel

Comment: do a `dd($search_text, $value_text, $change_content)` and check if there's any differences between the output from AWS and local

Comment: @apokryfos already did all are same. the difference is only in local str_replace return with replaced text but AWS not

Comment: If you use str_ireplace()  instead of str_replace(), what happens ?

Comment: @KenLee didn't try yet. Let me try

Comment: @KenLee same issue with str_ireplace also

Comment: If it is working fine in local then the problem is the either the path or permissions as @KenLee highlighted try doing this  copy your constants.php to a backup folder then remove everything except $config then add '   $g = fopen($config,"w");
fwrite($g,"Lorem Ipsum");
fclose($g);    '

Comment: Check your file for "lorem Ipsum" also check if the file constants.php is not created somewhere else within your subfolders

Comment: @KevinGales I am getting the file content before str_replacing. Also, I have changed content manually or testing and it returns the changed content as well. Let me check with the simple lorem_ipsum test.

Comment: Try running `dd(str_split($search_text), str_split($value_text), str_split($change_content))` and check how long the resulting arrays are and if there are any discrepencies (you probably can also use `var_export` on the result and copy the varialbe locally to write code to compare if the variables are too large)

Comment: What does your PHP Error log tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NOTE: No there is no extra addon/extension in PHP for str_replace.
> str_replace() is built in string function on PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7, PHP 8.

In your code, there can be 2 possible errors. As your code is running local and your files have write permissions.

1. The First point is - your `/config/constants.php` file is too big that's why the foreach loop is taken too much time and exit it but for this PHP should throw an error.
2. The Second point is - You are using laravel config and your `$searchfor` variable coming from `bootstrap/cache/config.php`. And you are replacing the value with the config cache value but maybe your `/config/constants.php` doesn't have this exact key-value or have some spaces between there. I think you got my point.

Answer (score 2):

Check these things are correct or not?

- Make sure your file exists in the right directory and have write permission
- Make sure your local and server `constants.php` has the same contents
- Remove your bootstrap/cache/config.php manually or by running `php artisan config:cache` this command re-caches your config again.